# как получить url адрес в js по котором переходишь

Tags: javascript

например я счас на сайте http://localhost:3000/more/16162c0f-29ba-4aea-85aa и получить 16162c0f-29ba-4aea-85aa но только на своем сайте . Нужно проверить url по которому перешел и встравить его в fetch и получить данные

Comment: В консоль прям в браузере выведите `window.location` и изучите объект. Там будет всё, что вам надо.

Comment: спасибо! помогло